# typeScript how to sort an array into an array

Tags: arrays, sorting, typescript

I Have a class

```
export class TestClass {
    id: number;
    text1: string;
    test2: string;
    text3: string;
```

and another

```
export class testClassRow {
    editable: boolean;
    testClass : TestClass ;
}
```

In my code , i have an array wich is filled with some data  , thus

```
x:testClassRow[];
```

I want to sort my x  and the sort key is text1.

I wrote a method that does the sort but it does not work
this is my method :

```
    sort(key, data) {

    if (this.key === key) {
        this.direction = this.direction * -1;
    } else {
        this.direction = 1;
    }

    this.key = key;
    data.applicationLink.sort((a, b) => {
        console.log('avlu' + a[key]);
        if (a[key] === b[key]) {
            return 0;
        }
        else if (a[key] > b[key]) {
            return 1 * this.direction;
        } else {
            return -1 * this.direction;
        }
    });
```

key has the value text1 for exemple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution

the call to sort method must be

```
  this._sorter.sort(key, this.testClassRow, o => o.testClass);
```

The sort method is

```
sort(key: string, data: any[], propertyRetriever: Function) {

    if (this.key === key) {
        this.direction = this.direction * -1;
    } else {
        this.direction = 1;
    }

    this.key = key;
    data.sort((a, b) => {
        if (propertyRetriever) {
            a = propertyRetriever(a);
            b = propertyRetriever(b);
        }
        else {
            a = a;
            b = b;
        }
        if (a[key] === b[key]) {
            return 0;
        }
        else if (a[key] > b[key]) {
            return 1 * this.direction;
        } else {
            return -1 * this.direction;
        }
    });
}
```